# git: remove commits from unnamed branch

Tags: git

After branching and merging, I deleted the branch, but the git graph still shows all the commits in the old branch, that now is unnamed.

```
A - B - I - J - - - - - K - L - M           (master)
     \                 /
      \ E - F - G - H /
```

I'd like to remove commits E, F, G and H, because the old branch doesn't exist anymore.

Edit

Just to be cleared, my goal is to change the history of master. The final tree should be:

```
A - B - I - J - K - L - M           (master)
```

So K shouldn't be a 3-way merge commit, but a standard commit with J as its parent.

If this was not possible, maybe I could have the following:

```
A - B - I - J - K' - L' - M'           (master)
```

Comment: Those commits are part of your master branch.

Comment: The commits as laid out on your graph are part of your current branch's history, and you can live fine with it.
You may *rewrite* the history of your `master` branch and change it to something else. You would have to explain what final history you have in mind though. You can search the internet for usages of "git rebase" and "squash and merge".

Comment: @LeGEC yes, E-F-G-H is ACTUALLY a part of my master branch, but I'd like to change the history. My goal is to have A-B-I-J-K-L-M or, if it was impossible, A-B-I-J-K'-L'-M'.

Comment: The question is phrased in a weird way. More to the point: did you intend to do a squash merge but then made a real merge? Or are you surprised that this happened? This might seem irrelevant to the precise goal but it is of pedagogical interest.

Comment: Do you want all the changes that E-F-G-H introduce, but just in a single commit K? Or do you want to not have those changes at all?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to recreate that merge commit as a squash merge (i.e. not a real merge). Make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes or stash them firs.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard J
```

Gives you

```
A - B - I - J                          (master)
     \       \
      \        - - - - - K - L - M
       \ E - F - G - H /
```

Squash-merge the last commit of your old branch:

```
git merge --squash H
```

```
A - B - I - J - K'                     (master)
     \       \
      \        - - - - - K - L - M
       \ E - F - G - H /
```

And then copy the commits that happened after the real merge:

```
git cherry-pick K..M
```

Leaving you with a final history of:

```
A - B - I - J - K' - L' - M'           (master)
     \       \
      \        - - - - - K - L - M
       \ E - F - G - H /
```

Only commits from master are reachable, so we can ignore the rest:

```
A - B - I - J - K' - L' - M'           (master)
```

Comment: there are then the known consequences of rewriting the history: the OP would then have to force push the `master` branch to the upstream. If on a shared repository, he would also have to inform his colleagues the the central branch changed and that they should take the appropriate actions if they have pending work depending on one of the rewritten commits.

Comment: @LeGEC correct. Since the OP stated explicitly »Just to be cleared [sic], my goal is to change the history of master« in their question, I assumed this was a given and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--first-parent` to not see merges from unnamed branches. `git log --oneline --graph --all --first-parent`. Maybe add `--date-order` if you like that sequence better.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I asked how to DELETE commits belonging to unnamed branches and not how to hide them in the log.

Comment: There's always `git replace --graft K K'; git filter-branch`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to undo the merge and add L and M again afterwards, but you could use squash merging for what you want.

This would squash all the changes from the branch into K'.

And, as you figured out correctly, that would alter the history of the master so that you would need to afterwards create L' and M' and then force-push.

The history would then look like this:

```
A - B - I - J - - - - - K' - L' - M'           (master)
     \                 /
      \ - - - - - - - /
```

---

If you for any reason need to not have a merge at all, you would need to rebase the branch changes on top of J, so that they can be added to the master branch directly. With rebase-merging, you are basically applying I and J between B and your first commit on the branch. After that, you can merge your branch into main (fast-forward) and the history will look like:

```
A - B - I - J - E' - F' - G' - H' - K' - L' - M'           (master)
```

---

With a combination of rebase-merging the master into your branch and then squash merging (fast-forward) your branch into the master, you will get what you want:

```
A - B - I - J - K' - L' - M'           (master)
```